# How to detect which element contains all other X elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(Hope this question hasn't been asked yet : I didn't find it via a keyword search)

I'd like to detect, using jQuery, which element (div, span, anything) contains all the other XKindOfElement.

Meaning, for example, if I have multiple checkboxes in my screen, I want to know which div contains all those checkboxes.

```
<div id="block1">
  <div id="underblock1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="1" />
    <div id="underunderblock1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="underblock2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, it will return the `div#block1` because only it contains all the `input[type="checkbox"]` of the page.

Hope you'll understand and could help me !

**UPDATE**

Thinking of something... What do you think about this process :

1. Check if our element exists in the page
2. If so, count how many of this element exists and save it (let's say `count`)
3. Check if the parent of the first element find contains all the `count` elements
4. If not, check if the parent of the parent contains all the `count` elements,
5. etc
6. When the checked parent does contain all the `count` elements: it is our "smallest global parent" !

Would it be ok or too slow, too "expansive"... ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: You can travel up the tree and look to see if the element(s) are in that, but it will be slow since it is multiple look ups. Might be better to add a class and look for that class if possible.

Comment: Thx @Thomas I actually thought about .parent() but it will return the parent of each elements instead of the global parent, won't it ?

epascarello By "to add a class", do you mean add a class to the elements for those I'm looking for the "global parent" ? If so, what would it change ?

Comment: parent will, but https://api.jquery.com/parents will get all of the parent elements. You are probably looking for https://api.jquery.com/has/ though...

Comment: @ca8msm I also thought about .has(), but how can it give me the smallest "global parent" which contains the ellements... See what I mean ?

Comment: Go through each of the searched elements, for all of their `parents()` set `data-counter` attribute on each of them to `data-counter`+1 (if it doesn't exist, set it to 0, then increment). The first parent that has `data-counter` equal to number of searched elements is the element you're searching for. Bear in mind that this approach will only work for one set of elements - do you want a `$.fn` function that does that?

Comment: use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) in jquery

Comment: @eithedog It's exactly what I was thinking about with my update, but you're saying it in a better way. If you have the time to, I'll be glad to use your $.fn function :). In any cases, thx for your confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with all the jQuery helper methods, but this approach might work for you:

- Collect all the elements you want to be included
- Collect their `parents` arrays and reverse them: all these arrays now start with: `html > body` and continue all the way to the actual element
- loop through a parent array and check if the other parent arrays have the same element at the current index
- the first element that doesn't match marks the index of the last shared parent

Note: you might want to refactor the code a bit to make sure you don't run into any errors for edge cases.

```js
var required = $("input[type=checkbox]");

var getClosestParent = function(elements) {
  var maxLength = 0;
  var allParents = [];

  elements.each(function(i, el) {
    var parents = $(el).parents().toArray().reverse();
    maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, parents.length);
    allParents.push(parents);
  });

  var ref = allParents[0];
  var others = allParents.slice(1);

  for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < others.length; j += 1) {
      if (ref[i] !== others[j][i]) {
        return ref[i - 1];
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}

console.log(getClosestParent(required).id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
  <div id="underblock1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="1" />
    <div id="underunderblock1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="underblock2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It helps a lot. Now I'm wondering what is the best way to do : starting with `html > body > etc` or starting with `parent > parentofparent > parentofparentofparent`. You know what I mean ? The idea is the same (but this time the number of `elements` is calculated before), but what's the fastest, the best, the wonderfulest ? :)

Comment: The point of starting at `html` is that you can use the index to compare against the others. If you don't reverse, finding the first common element takes more iterations (you'll have to use an `indexOf` inside a `forEach`). Since the current equality comparer does a reference check, it's really fast.

Comment: Ok I see your point. But if I understand well, with your method you start by getting all the parents of the element, then checking the list of those parents to compare them and stop when the good one is found (well, when the good one +1 is found ^^ ). Isn't it longer than : 1) Get the number of all required elements on the page, 2) Take the first required element, 3) Check how many required elements his parent contains, 4) If it does not contain everything, check the parent of his parent, 5) If it does not contain everything, check the parent of the parent of his parent... ?

Comment: Any DOM element holds a reference to its parent. That's why creating an array of parent elements is a really fast operation. `while(el.parent) { arr.push(el.parent); el = el.parent; }` is all it takes. Using css selectors to search the DOM is a whole different story: every element has to be checked to see if it meets a requirement. I'm no expert, so I could be wrong, but I'm guessing this approach is more than fast enough and faster than your suggested alternative :) Might be interesting to create a test project to compare the different methods!

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna trust you. You seem to understand all of this better than me (yeah well, it's not difficult) ! Thx for your function !!

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of arrays for each of the parents, then loop over them until you find a miss-match:-

```js
var parents = new Array();
var minDepth = (Math.pow(2, 53) - 1);
$('[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, e) {
  parents.push($(e).parents().get().reverse());
  if (minDepth > parents[i].length)
    minDepth = parents[i].length;
});
var topParent, testParent;
finished:
  for (var i = 0; i < minDepth; i++) {
    testParent = parents[0][i];
    for (var j = 0; j < parents.length; j++) {
      if (parents[j][i] != testParent)
        break finished;
    }
    topParent = parents[0][i];
  }
console.log(topParent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
  <div id="underblock1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="1" />
    <div id="underunderblock1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="underblock2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, I'm answering to myself thx to you guys. I thought about @user3297291 said, however I still think starting from the element itself is faster than starting from `html > body > etc`.

So I make this, what do you think ?

```js
var required = jQuery("input[type=checkbox]");

var getClosestGlobalParent = function(elements) {
  var count = elements.length,
   result = null;
  if(count) { 
   if(count > 1) {
    jQuery(elements[0]).parents().each(function(i, el) {
     if(jQuery(this).find(elements).length == count) { 
      result = jQuery(this); // We also can return "this"
      return false; // If the parent is found, we stop the .each loop
     }
    });
   } else {
    result = jQuery(elements[0]).parent(); // If there's only one element, his closest parent IS his .parent()
   }
  }
  
  return result;
 }

 console.log(getClosestGlobalParent(required).attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="under_container">
    <div id="block1">
      <div id="underblock1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="1" /> Val1
        <div id="underunderblock1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="2" /> Val2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="underblock2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="3" /> Val3
        <br /><input type="checkbox" name="thing[]" value="4" /> Val4
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.sharedParents = function(){
    if (this.length == 0)
        return this;

    var parents = $(this.get(0)).parents();
    for (var i=0; i<parents.length; i++)
        for (var j=1; j<this.length; j++)
            if (!$.contains(parents[i], this[j]))
            {
                delete parents[i];
                break;
            }

    return parents;
}
```

For given set of elements - get all the parents of the first element. Then for all the other elements check if given parents contain those elements. The result is a list of all parents containing all elements, and, as such, the deepest parent will be the first entry of that list.

https://jsfiddle.net/hwte8n3w/